# API key for Google chart required?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-visualization

I am using a 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart on a website to create a really simple representation of distributions around the world. For example, we have 3 people in the USA, 4 people in Sweden and so on.
Everything works fine, but my browser sometimes warns me that I need to specify an API key.

Now my question is: Why do I need an API key when I only use static data?

Thank you very much for your answer in advance

```
{
  type: 'GeoChart',
  columnNames: ['Country', 'No'],
  data: [
    ["United States", 2], ["Sweden", 4],...]
  ],
  options: {
    region: 'world',
  }
}
```

Comment: because you are trying to use google cloud service and they need to authenticate user so they need api key

Comment: `GeoChart` is the only google visualization that requires an api key...